# Using a transistor as a switch to let a 9V Battery flow

Tags: transistors, batteries, switches

I'm fairly new to electric engineering and wanted to try building the following circuit:

3.3V Power Source (On/Off Controlled via. Microcontroller ESP8266)

9V Power Source (Battery)

Transistor/MOSFET

The 9V Power Source should only flow if the 3.3V Power Source is active. 
| e.g. Microcontroller turns on 3.3 Power Source -> 9V Power Source flows and powers XYZ.

I've tried simulating it via. an online tool but couldn't really get it to work, can someone give me a heads up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you click Edit on your post, you'll find a small icon for a schematics tool in the editor. If you show the schematic you've got right now, it's easier to get suggestions for improvements.

Comment: @Dampmaskin Thanks for the heads up! I will do so next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of MOSFETs can not be controlled (or turn on) by 3.3 V. It needs 10 volts at least. So, I suggest using a transistor.

There're many ways and configurations that makes you control your load using a transistor and this depends on your application or your load so, It would be better if you mentioned your load in your question. Anyway, I will give you a general idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVTABr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's how the circuit works:
I assume that you want to control an LED using your Microcontroller. I mean the LED is your load.

When you apply a signal to the gate of the transistor (3.3V), The transistor turns ON and allows the current to flow from the collector to the emitter and the LED turns on.

When the output of the Microcontroller is 0V, No signal is applied to the gate of the transistor. So, The transistor turns OFF and prevent current from flowing and the LED is OFF.

A 9V can not applied directly to an LED to prevent damaging of the led. So, you need R1 to protect it.

When you read the datasheet of the Microcontroller, You will find that it can provide a limited current from its output. You must not exceed this limit. So, you need to use R2 to protect the your Microcontroller and your transistor as well (Base current should be limited too).

Comment: Hey,

thanks for the answer. The load from the microcontroller is 3.3V, but I dont think you got the Problem right. When the microcontroller is letting energy flow to the transistor i want the full 9V from the battery to flow somewhere else where it powers  device XYZ.

Comment: It does. The LED and R1 is device XYZ.

Comment: You can replace the combination of ( R1 & LED ) with device xyz

Comment: @Michael George *"Most of MOSFETs can not be controlled (or turn on) by 3.3 V. It needs 10 volts at least"*. There are still MOSFETs which could be turn on from 3V3, the famous BSS138 is one of them. But then, it depends on the application. A MOSFET will definitely help going around the current limit constrain you talked about.